# Prevent a command being executed from a source'd file in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

For security purposes, how can I prevent a command being executed in a file that is `source`'d?
For example:

```
#!/bin/sh
source file.cfg
```

Wanted:

```
get="value"
```

Unintended:

```
command
```

Comment: Don't source it.  When you source a file, you are having the shell interpret the contents.  If you don't trust the contents, don't trust the file at all, and therefore don't source it.  Would you want to allow `other="$(command argument)"`? You could think about parsing the sourced file and sourcing it only if it meets your standards, but that is hard.

Comment: If this is a case of vendor supplied code, and you are required to run it try an alias. For example, the echo command is pretty much harmless:  alias  command='echo "hi there" > /dev/null'

Answer (score 13):

You could use a mechanism like in `Python`. Define variables and/or functions and put executable commands into a conditional block:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Variables and functions comes here
a=1
b=2

function foo() {
    echo "bar"
}

# Put executable commands here
if [ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ] ; then
    foo
fi
```

If you `chmod +x` the file and run it or run it through `bash file.sh` the executable commands in the conditional statement will get executed. If you source the file only variables and functions will get imported.

Comment: In addition, if `foo()` accepts command line arguments, forward the arguments by `foo "$@"`.

Comment: I found this answer to be useful, but I would add that since `BASH_SOURCE` is an array, you should reference the first element like this `if [ "$0" = "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" ]; then`. Edit: Also I'd just run  `[ "$0" = "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" ] && foo "$@"`

Answer (score 7):

Long story short, you can't. We could debate how to try to prevent some commands from being executed but if security is the major concern here, `source` is a no-go. You are looking for a proper configuration facility — while `source` is intended to execute *code*.

For example, the following code provides a trivial key-value configuration file parsing:

```
while read -r x; do
    declare +x -- "${x}"
done < file.cfg
```

But this is both far from the flexibility `source` gives you, and it is far from perfectly secure solution either. It doesn't handle any specific escaping, multi-line variables, comments… and it also doesn't filter the assigned variables, so the config can override your precious variables. The extra `+x` argument to `declare` ensures that the config file at least won't modify environment exported to programs.

If you really want to go this route, you can try to improve this. But if you are really worried about security, you should think twice before using shell script at all. Writing proper shell script is not trivial at all, and it is full of pitfalls.

Comment: Mostly configuration files are *meant* to overwrite default values. Having this, why not just sourcing a configuration file? Also the `read` loop won't work if there are executable commands in `file.cfg`

Comment: Yes. I had imagined some kind trick.
The source is a file with public access, where you get only simple variables as:
`var1="string"
var2="string"`
by no means can contain a command unless it is a malicious command

Comment: Note that my snippet reads `""` literally in config. To get them bash-interpreted you'd have to work on it more :).

Answer (score 0):

Something basic, might work:

```
name="$(sed -n 1p < source_file | grep -o 'name="[^"]*' | grep -o '[^"]*$')"

lastname="$(sed -n 2p < source_file | grep -o 'lastname="[^"]*' | grep -o '[^"]*$')"

age="$(sed -n 3p < source_file | grep -o 'age="[^"]*' | grep -o '[^"]*$')"
```

Next, check the parameters if they meet certain standards for example if it matches a name of a database (`$LIST_NAMES`) or if you have a certain amount of character string, ect.

```
if ! grep -Fox "$name" <<<"$LIST_NAMES"; then exit 1; fi

if [ $(wc -c <<<"$age") -gt 3 ]; then exit 1; fi
```

then taken only the lines useful to prevent the rest.

```
head -n3 < source_file > source_file.tmp

source 'source_file.tmp'
```